# Why when I use wget for a website does it download additional parts of the website?

Tags: wget

I'm using

```
wget -mirror https://www.website.com/sub/folders/here/
```

and want to download all of the content in the subfolders of the current location i.e. "/here/" . But instead, this command starts from

```
https://www.website.com/
```

and downloads everything that is a subfolder of the website, meaning not only from /sub/ but every other existing subfolder and its content. Anyone know of a better command to do this? And, why does this command not work? Just curious.

Comment: Possibly related from stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it

Comment: Related. The selected answer solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @mikanim cool but you should mark waltinator as answer because he's 100% right about why that was happening.

Comment: He's right about the typo --mirror but I tried --mirror after his correction and it doesn't solve the issue. It still downloads everything.

Comment: Probably what you need to use is `wget --show-progress -r -np https://www.website.com/sub/folders/here/` See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202699/968501) for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read `man wget`? The option you want is `--mirror`, documented as

```
   -m
   --mirror
       Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent
       to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing.
```

By typing `-mirror`, you've specified `-m`, `-i`, `-r` (3 times), and `-o`. These single letter options have their own meanings, see `man wget`.