# Wget batch of files fails, curl works, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: command-line, wget

I am trying to download the entire directory from this website: https://data.geobasis-bb.de/geobasis/daten/dgm/xyz/

What I tried is:

```
wget --show-progress -A 'dgm_*.zip' https://data.geobasis-bb.de/geobasis/daten/dgm/xyz/ -P /run/media/usr1/exthdd/dgm
```

What it should do, as far as I understand it, is download all files that fit the name schmea *dgm_*.zip*. However it returns only:

```
--2020-01-13 14:50:11--  https://data.geobasis-bb.de/geobasis/daten/dgm/xyz/
CA-Zertifikat »/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt« wurde geladen
Auflösen des Hostnamens data.geobasis-bb.de (data.geobasis-bb.de)… 194.99.76.18, 194.76.232.112
Verbindungsaufbau zu data.geobasis-bb.de (data.geobasis-bb.de)|194.99.76.18|:443 … verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet … 200 OK
Länge: nicht spezifiziert [text/html]
Wird in »/run/media/lgoldmann/lg_backup_diss/dgm/index.html.tmp.2« gespeichert.

index.html.tmp.2                             [   <=>                                                                             ]   2,65M  4,69MB/s    in 0,6s    

2020-01-13 14:50:15 (4,69 MB/s) - »/run/media/lgoldmann/lg_backup_diss/dgm/index.html.tmp.2« gespeichert [2778920]
```

The website also offers a pretyped comand for curl, which works just fine, but I am trying to find out, what went wrong with my wget command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-r` option to get all links on the page or, otherwise, `wget` will get only the first page that is served by the web server (i.e. default or index) and quit.

It is wise when using `-r` to use `-np` to exclude parent links and make sure `wget` does not follow links that are one level or more up.

Also you might not want `wget` to rebuild the directory structure of the site locally and just download the files, so also use the `-nd` option like so:

```
wget --show-progress -A 'dgm_*.zip' -r -np -nd https://data.geobasis-bb.de/geobasis/daten/dgm/xyz/ -P /run/media/usr1/exthdd/dgm
```